# how to integrate with square root with mode?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I want to integrate

$$\int_{-1}^{2}\sqrt{|x|} \, \mathrm dx$$

But I dont know how to do it should I integrate it fist from $-1$ to $0$ and then from $0$ to $2$ making one of equation in minus other in plus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $$\int_{-1}^{2} \sqrt{|x|}dx = \int_{-1}^{0}\sqrt{-x}dx +  \int_{0}^{2}\sqrt{x}dx$$

Comment: I am thinking of this to...but isn't \sqrt{-x} unreal number

Comment: What is the definition of $|x|$?Every $-1\leq x \leq 0$ you take $-x$, which is positive.

Comment: for x > 0 its positive for x < 0 its negative...hence it will give u positive answer

Comment: It's $\geq 0$. But that's correct!

Answer (score 0):

$$\int_{-1}^2 \sqrt{|x|}dx=\int_{-1}^0 \sqrt{-x}dx+ \int_0^2 \sqrt{x}dx$$
$$$$
$$\int_{-1}^0 \sqrt{-x}dx: \\ \text{ We set } -x=u \Rightarrow -dx=du \\ \text{ When }x=-1 \Rightarrow u=1, \text{ when } x=0 \Rightarrow u=0$$
So: $$\int_{-1}^0 \sqrt{-x}dx=-\int_1^0 \sqrt{u}du=\int_0^{1} \sqrt{u}du=\left[\frac{2u^{\frac{3}{2}}}{3}\right]_0^1=\frac{2}{3}$$
$$$$
Also:

$$\int_0^2 \sqrt{x}dx=\left[\frac{2x^{\frac{3}{2}}}{3}\right]_0^2=\frac{2^{\frac{5}{2}}}{3}$$

Therefore:

$$\int_{-1}^2 \sqrt{|x|}dx=\frac{2}{3}+\frac{2^{\frac{5}{2}}}{3}$$